# reason for "not for diagnostic use" advice in protocols

Tags: protocol

I read "not for diagnostic use" in every protocol i saw. why is it so? 
which differences have the kits and material that are used for diagnostic purposes?

Answer (score 3):

the FDA has to approve diagnostics - a rigorous and expensive process.  Its a legal distinction, but also one which conveys a significant level of usefulness and reliability.

Comment: The quality controls (GMP, GLP and so on) which have to be implemented for diagnostic kits are also ways more complicated, what makes these kits more expensive.

Comment: Yes definitely - it takes years and $millions usually.  and its effectiveness has to be clear and reproducible.